# Android - sqlite in clause using string values from array?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I want to execute a sqlite query, I have a `String` :

```
 String A = "AB-CDFER-GTDOL";
 String[] parts = Pattern.compile("-", Pattern.LITERAL).split(A);
```

Now I need to use from `parts` in my `query`.

```
cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Comment in" + ?????, null);
```

How I can use from `parts` in my `query`.

For example I need to have `("AB","CDFER","GTDOL")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile a string after split:

```
         String A = "AB-CDFER-GTDOL";
         String[] parts = Pattern.compile("-", Pattern.LITERAL).split(A);
    // build the params string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for(String param:parts){
    // you can also enclose it in quotes
    sb.append",".append('"').append(param).append('"');
    }
    // remove 1st comma from sb.
    final String params = sb.toString().substr(1);
```

The trick here is to compile needed string as `"AB","CDFER","GTDOL"`. Now you can pass this string as a ONE paramenter.

```
cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Comment in(?)", new String[]{params});
```

Comment: How I can use : `%` in `cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Comment in(?)", new String[]{params});`

Comment: for example :`SELECT tittle,parentID,_id FROM WebSite_CategoryBack WHERE tittle in ('%ACFD%','%SEESD%')`

Comment: Add `%` to the params builder code. And here, on SO, you have to accept answer if its really answers your question.

Comment: In this query :`SELECT tittle,parentID,_id FROM WebSite_CategoryBack WHERE tittle in ('%ACFD%','%SEESD%')` I use from `%` but don't get me any result.

Comment: Do the same I did with the quotes. Looks like you are not familiar with Java at all...

Comment: I do same your response but symbol `%` don't work at statement 'IN' I need to use from `IN` same `LIKE`

Comment: Why are you trying to put % into `in` directly? What do you expect to get? `in (%'ACFD','SEESD')`? You have to enclose EVERY parameter you pass to `SQL` `IN` statement. `sb.append",".append('"').append('%').append(param).append('%').append('"');` ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem:

You can split your string in the following way:

```
String A = "AB-CDFER-GTDOL";
 String[] parts = A.split("-");
```

Now your parts array will have the following values:

```
parts[0] = "AB";
parts[1] = "CDFER" etc..
```

Similarly you can use these value in your sql query as needed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `query` Method from Android SQLDatabase. This is the Documentation for it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query

You could implement it like the following:

```
 String A = "AB-CDFER-GTDOL";
 String[] parts = A.split("-");
 cursor = sql.query("MyTable", null, "Comment = ?", parts, null, null, null, null);
```

A helpful Article about SQL in Android: http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/